# Passing coordinates values from google sheets columns in static map URL

Tags: image, google-sheets, mapbox, arcgis

I've been trying to fill a google spreadsheet column with static satellite maps giving the coords from latitude and longitude columns.

Something like this:

```
=IMAGE("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/"&K1&","&J1&",14.25,0,60/600x600?access_token=API_KEY")
```

My problem is constructing the API call using Lat, long pairs stored in the Google Sheet cells.

I am getting a range of errors from both Google sheets and mapbox, so obviously my syntax within sheets is bad. When I type the url in a browser, with hard-coded lat,lng the correct map image is displayed.

A typical Google error is

> Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But
>   'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/' is a
>   text and cannot be coerced to a number

Can someone please assist?

Comment: "It doesn't work"?.. Best you provide details of any error messages or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Hi!. Thanks a lot ofr your time. I get no ERROR message. Just Blank

Comment: You should be able to enter that URL in your browser. What does it return? If not a proper reply then it will give an error message - like 404 or whatever. When its working in browser then its easy to get it working in Google sheets.

Comment: Hi again! If I write the URL on the browser naming the cells like this: `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/"&J1&","&K1&",14.25,0,60/600x600?access_token=API_KEY`  I get: `{"message":"Longitude, latitude, zoom, bearing and pitch must all be numbers."}`

Comment: And if I write on the URL with the coords numbers in the browser it shows the static map.

Comment: It may not like "&J1&","&K1&" if it expects a lat long in numeric form. I guess J1 and K1 cells in your sheet contain lat and long, right? Try your URL in browser with actual lat, longs.

Comment: Yes! That's what I've done. And it works fine like this.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem to pass the image URL with the google spreadsheet values

Comment: Correct, and now the problem is to construct a workable URL in sheets. I will take a look and get back.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate

Comment: Ok check the reply below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had Lat, long wrong way around. Some mapping systems require Lat, Lng and others Lng, Lat (go figure!)

If you change as below, you will get an image, but you may need to play with other parameters to get it working as you need.

```
=IMAGE("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/"&K3&","&J3&",14.25,0,60/600x600?access_token=API_KEY")
```

You can also use the form below which is another way to construct the API string from the component parts.

```
=image(concatenate("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/",K3,",",J3,",14.25,0,60/600x600?access_token=ACCESS_KEY"))
```

In both cases, the parameters after the Coordinates represent the desired zoom, orientation angles and image resolution. You can play around with image formats here https://www.mapbox.com/help/static-api-playground/.

Also note that you have options in Google sheets to adjust how the image is displayed (resize, stretch etc) in the cell, using the IMAGE parameters. This is explained here https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en

Comment: No. It doesn't work. Like this it's consider as a string not value. `Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.`

Comment: Why I'm getting so many negative points? The question is well formulated. The answer is not that easy....

Comment: This is how I've written it: `=IMAGE("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/"+&K1&+","+&J1&+",14.25,0,60/600x600?access_token=API_KEY")` with this new ERROR: `Error
Formula parse error.` Thank you for your time. Really appreciate

Comment: You need to try what I suggested - which is not the same as you say you did. Look carefully.

Comment: People down vote if they think you did not research enough yourself. This is subjective and not worth worrying about.

Comment: =IMAGE("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/"+"&K1&"+"&J1&"+"14.25,0,60/600x600?access_token=API_KEY") This is the first thing that I've tried. Still the same ERROR: `Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.` It expecst values not string

Comment: Ok why not post a link to your sheet and I can take a look.

Comment: .../api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/static/"+"&K1&"+"&J1&"+"14.25,0,60/600x600?access_token=API_KEY Here you can see it better. Is the same ERROR

Comment: see adjusted reply - we are moving in right direction - but probably not yet fully OK

Comment: Yes. But Lat Lon I changed already before. What I see is that you added a 2 value to mode. What does it? Thank you a lot or your time :)

Comment: You can have 1,2,3,4 to adjust the image resizing. I have to go now but will have another look tomorrow if still not solved. I need to read the mapbox API doco in more depth

Comment: Thanks for all the support